# I'm attempting to deploy Spring Boot Cloud Gateway on Open Liberty; however, it's throwing a FileNotFoundException for WebMvcConfigurer.class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, websphere, spring-cloud-gateway, open-liberty

My requirement is to run spring boot Gateway on Open Liberty. To get started I've generated a basic spring boot project using the spring boot initializr with the [following configurations](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.1.4&packaging=war&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=cloud-gateway)

I've added the `liberty-maven-plugin` and `maven-resources-plugin`, set the `finalName` for the `server.xml` file to be picked up.

When running the project using the `mvn liberty:run` command I'm thrown the following error

```
[INFO]   .   ____          _            __ _ _
[INFO]  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
[INFO] ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
[INFO]  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
[INFO]   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
[INFO]  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[INFO]  :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.4)
[INFO] 2023-10-03T10:08:26.208+05:30  INFO 22600 --- [ecutor-thread-8] com.example.demo.ServletInitializer      : Starting ServletInitializer using Java 17.0.6 with PID 22600 (C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\demo\target\classes started by UserName in C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\demo\target\liberty\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer)
[INFO] 2023-10-03T10:08:26.211+05:30  INFO 22600 --- [ecutor-thread-8] com.example.demo.ServletInitializer      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"   
[INFO] 2023-10-03T10:08:26.728+05:30  WARN 22600 --- [ecutor-thread-8] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refre
sh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.example.demo.DemoApplication]: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
[INFO] 2023-10-03T10:08:26.765+05:30  INFO 22600 --- [ecutor-thread-8] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 
[INFO]
[INFO] Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[INFO] 2023-10-03T10:08:26.803+05:30 ERROR 22600 --- [ecutor-thread-8] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
[INFO]
[INFO] org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.example.demo.DemoApplication]: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:527) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:729) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at java.base/java.lang.Iterable.forEach(Iterable.java:75) ~[na:na]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:726) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:697) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12] 
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:182) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:415) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:287) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:344) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:115) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:771) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]      
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:589) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:439) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:174) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:154) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4] 
[INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:96) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:171) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebApp.java:2578) ~[na:na]
[INFO]  at [internal classes]
[INFO]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) ~[na:na]
[INFO]  at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) ~[na:na]
[INFO]  at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:857) ~[na:na]
[INFO] Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
[INFO]  at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:211) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:54) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:48) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.createMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:86) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.boot.type.classreading.ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(ConcurrentReferenceCachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:73) ~[spring-boot-3.1.4.jar:3.1.4]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:81) ~[spring-core-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.asSourceClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:613) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$SourceClass.getInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:939) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processInterfaces(ConfigurationClassParser.java:379) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:325) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:243) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:365) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:265) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:243) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:517) ~[spring-context-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
[INFO]  ... 39 common frames omitted
PS C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\demo>
```

What my `Project Structure` looks like

```
├───src
│   ├───main
│   │   ├───java
│   │   │   └───com
│   │   │       └───example
│   │   │           └───demo
│   │   │                   DemoApplication.java
│   │   │                   ServletInitializer.java
│   │   │
│   │   ├───liberty
│   │   │   └───config
│   │   │           server.xml
│   │   │
│   │   └───resources
│   │       │   application.properties
│   │       │
│   │       ├───static
│   │       └───templates
│   └───test
│       └───java
└───target
```

`pom.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2022.0.4</spring-cloud.version>
        <snakeyaml.version>2.1</snakeyaml.version>
        <netty.version>4.1.86.Final</netty.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <finalName>demo</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.openliberty.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

`application.properties`

```
server.port= 8181

spring.main.web-application-type=reactive
spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

`DemoApplication,java`

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

`ServletInitializer.java`

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(DemoApplication.class);
    }

}
```

`server.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<server>

    <featureManager>
        <feature>servlet-6.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

    <httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="8080" httpsPort="-1" id="defaultHttpEndpoint" />

    <webApplication contextRoot="demo" location="demo.war"/>

    <applicationManager autoExpand="true" />

    <webContainer deferServletLoad="false"/>

</server>
```

From my understanding, `spring-cloud-starter-gateway` is not compatible with `spring-boot-starter-web` That has the `WebMvcConfigurer` class.

Just to feed my curiosity, I've added the `spring-webmvc` dependency any ways. As expected, the application failed to run with the follwing Exception.

```
[INFO]   .   ____          _            __ _ _
[INFO]  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
[INFO] ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
[INFO]  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
[INFO]   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
[INFO]  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
[INFO]  :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.4)
[INFO] 2023-10-03T10:24:50.586+05:30  INFO 4424 --- [ecutor-thread-3] com.example.demo.ServletInitializer      : Starting ServletInitializer using Java 17.0.6 with PID 4424 (C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\demo\target\classes started by UserName in C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\demo\target\liberty\wlp\usr\servers\defaultServer)
[INFO] 2023-10-03T10:24:50.587+05:30  INFO 4424 --- [ecutor-thread-3] com.example.demo.ServletInitializer      : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"    
[INFO] 2023-10-03T10:24:51.314+05:30  INFO 4424 --- [ecutor-thread-3] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=f2be7fe6-1cee-39f4-98e2-a0aa21ddc1eb
[INFO] 2023-10-03T10:24:51.382+05:30  INFO 4424 --- [ecutor-thread-3] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 752 ms
[INFO] 2023-10-03T10:24:51.562+05:30  WARN 4424 --- [ecutor-thread-3] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refres
h attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayClassPathWarningAutoConfiguration$Spr
ingMvcFoundOnClasspathConfiguration': Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.cloud.gateway.config.GatewayClassPathWarningAutoConfiguration$SpringMvcFoundOnClasspathConfiguration]: Constructor threw exception
[INFO] 2023-10-03T10:24:51.575+05:30  INFO 4424 --- [ecutor-thread-3] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 
[INFO]
[INFO] Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
[INFO] 2023-10-03T10:24:51.600+05:30 ERROR 4424 --- [ecutor-thread-3] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 
[INFO]
[INFO] ***************************
[INFO] APPLICATION FAILED TO START
[INFO] ***************************
[INFO]
[INFO] Description:
[INFO]
[INFO] Spring MVC found on classpath, which is incompatible with Spring Cloud Gateway.
[INFO]
[INFO] Action:
[INFO]
[INFO] Please set spring.main.web-application-type=reactive or remove spring-boot-starter-web dependency.
```

As the logs suggested, I've added the property `spring.main.web-application-type=reactive` in the `application.properties` file. This time there was a bean naming conflict

```
[INFO] ***************************
[INFO] APPLICATION FAILED TO START
[INFO] ***************************
[INFO]
[INFO] Description:
[INFO]
[INFO] The bean 'errorAttributes', defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/error/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration.class], could not be registered. A
 bean with that name has already been defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/error/ErrorWebFluxAutoConfiguration.class] and overriding is disabled.
[INFO]
[INFO] Action:
[INFO]
[INFO] Consider renaming one of the beans or enabling overriding by setting spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true
```

Although, I believe making `spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding` to `true` is not the right approach. I went with the suggestion only to end up where I started with, the initial `FileNotFoundException` for `WebMvcConfigurer.class`.

Comment: Your application is schizophrenic you are specifiing it as reactive but are deploying to a servlet container (which isn't in the supported list for Reactive servers). While starting it detects the servlet classes and thus tries (needs) to configure this (due to your `SpringBootServletInitializer`. So you need to add `spring-boot-starter-web` to include the right classes to at least start the application. Which I then suspect will fail as it isn't a reactive implementation.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, you're absolutely correct that my application's current configuration may seem inconsistent. I should clarify that my primary intention is to experiment. If you have any helpful documentation or resources that you could point me to, or if you could guide me in the right direction to learn more about optimizing my application for a reactive approach, I would greatly appreciate it

Comment: If you want full reactive don't use liberty, as that is only a Servlet container. Using Reactive on that is supported but only the async part as it will adapt for the async servlet API. You won't get any of the backpressure and other features of reactive. Adding the `spring-boot-starter-web` dependency will probably make it start but it won't make it fully reactive.